# Layout being triggered on css transform

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have an element `div` which has the following styles —

```
  height: '100%',
  willChange: 'transform',
  marginRight: '15px',
  transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
```

On touch move event I am updating the elements `style.transform` as follows —

```
el.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * x - 100}%)`
```

Apparently as the the information here https://csstriggers.com/transform
These changes are not supposed to cause any `Layout` updates. But I still see a lot of `Layout` events on the timeline.

Comment: Show some code.  Layout updates can be caused by something else.

Comment: @tushar could you provide js fiddle for that? i am raising this issue with csstriggers as well to learn more insight about your question. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/css-triggers/issues/23

Comment: @Tushar the accepted answer is not correct. If you don't show any code, we cannot help you. Using *transform does not force any layout*.

Answer (score 1):

Css transforms is one of the property that if used through Javascript does cause browser to synchoronously calculate style and layout a.k.a reflow or [Layout trashing](http://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/). Have a look at this to learn about all possible elements that can cause Layout trashing https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a 
 But here is the thing, According to my understandings, Transform is one of the property which browser can animate very cheaply with ease. and

> transforms are the best properties to animate because the GPU can
>   assist with the heavy lifting ref: [HTML5rocks high performance animations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

There is a nice example given on the topic of **Avoid large, complex layouts and layout thrashing** on developers.google, where at the bottom you could see a example of offsetWidth on reading writing DOM. I think you can try that with transform, i reckon it could be helpful.

EDIT: @Tushar could you provide js fiddle for your problem or advised how can i regenerate the exact probelem? I am raising this issue with csstriggers on git as well to learn more insight about your question. github.com/GoogleChrome/css-triggers/issues/23

Comment: @Tushar Transform comes under the **getComputedStyle** method. So, as i mentioned in the answer, when transform requested/called in JavaScript, it cause layout trashing. [Original Source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/CSSComputedStyleDeclaration.cpp&sq=package:chromium&l=457&dr=C&q=isLayoutDependent) Confirm this also from  gist link **what-forces-layout** by paulirish. bottom line, csstriggers is not incorrect. It is wrong in the case only, If you are calling that property through Js.